# Create a geographical network map

Tags: python

What is the best way to visualize a network geographically in python?

I have some cities in the US with lat/long coordinates.  Some of those cities are connected by links.

I'd like to wind up with a map where each link has an assigned color and the (labeled) nodes are placed appropriately based on lat/long.

I'd prefer to get a png as an output and my preference is to do this in python.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using **[pydot](http://code.google.com/p/pydot/)** to work with **[Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/)**. Graphviz can export to a whole lot of different formats, has been around forever, and does quite well (in my experience) no matter how large a data set you throw at it.

Comment: I tried that, but wasn't able to get it to work with lat/long.  It kept applying one of it's layout algorithms.  It's probably a failure on my part, but regardless, I couldn't make it work.